# How to replace Sharepoint Forefront based authentication with REST API Call for XAmarin - IOS

Tags: sharepoint, xamarin, sharepoint-2013

I am started creating an application in Xamarin-IOS, Where I need to authenticate into a Sharepoint site. I am using (https://xyz-public.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/authenticate.aspx?Source=/)

[image]

kind of link for authentication purpose.During the time it is asking for **MS Forefront threat management gateway** for authentication So my doubt here is, Is there any way to authenticate in app into my share point site without using( Forefront Threat management gate way) using Sharepoint **REST API** service.

As per the requirement I can't able to use web browser for authentication process.

I don't have much expertise in share point authentication. So please help me. I am not expecting a full end to end answer instead please guide me to implement the same from my end.

**NB: The app is running in Enterprise environment.**

Answer (score 5):

You have a few options. Forefront is (by default) configured to support Basic fallback if you specify a certain client with the UserAgent. By testing I found out that you should create an UserAgent with "MSRPC" in it and removing all the values a normal browser might set in the UserAgent (Mozilla/IE/WebKit)

This way your Forefront will fallback to Http Basic Authentication, with can be set in the HTTPclient.defaultrequestheaders.

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
            //or handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@domain", "password");
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                //Clear the useragent field
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Clear();
                //add MSRPC
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue("MSRPC"));

                var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://urlProtectedByForeFront");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you can provide a sample, That would be great.. If I follow the above steps, Is it possible for me to authenticate by using HttpWebRequest from my client application

Comment: Could you please provide some samples or code snippets. I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I think it is not possible to implement the same with HttpWebRequest / HttpClient

Comment: Changing my User-Agent from "(Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0))" 
to 
"MSRPC" worked